# Can map custome domain to AWS Lambda Function without API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, custom-domain

I'm new to work with AWS now, my first approach is AWS Lambda,
so:

- Can we call AWS functions directly without AWS API Gateway?
- Can we map Domain to function URL without AWS API Gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we call AWS functions directly without AWS API Gateway?

You can call Lambda functions directly through the `lambda:Invoke` [API-call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html), but that requires you having valid credentials to your AWS Account and the required permissions to do that.

> Can we map Domain to function URL without AWS API Gateway?

No, Lambda basically runs code in response to events and there are two ways to get it to respond to HTTP(S) events:

- [Integrate the Lambda function with an API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html)
- [Integrate the Lambda function with an Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html)

You can set up your custom domain with both the API Gateway and an application load balancer though.